# Fragment not filling fragmentContainerView when rotated 90 degrees in the View

Tags: java, android, xml

I am constructing a UI that has multiple of the same fragment displayed on the screen at a time. 2 fragmentContainerViews are rotated 90 degrees and 1 is normal. The on not rotated fills the container but the 2 that are rotated don't fill the container vertically.

This is what the display looks like when ran:

[activity screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF8w3.png)

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ThreePlayerActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView3"
        android:name="com.example.mtgcommanderapp.PlayerFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragmentContainerView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView4"
            android:name="com.example.mtgcommanderapp.PlayerFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:rotation="90" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView5"
            android:name="com.example.mtgcommanderapp.PlayerFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:rotation="-90" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also if anyone knows a good resource for learning how to format an activity that is more in-depth?